# How do i re-enable usb in mac?

Tags: macos

I just saw how we can disable in mac USB devices by the following link

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2105022

But i don't know how to re-enable this?

Answer (score 1):

If you deleted the system file, you can either

1. restore that file from a backup
2. restore the entire system from a back up
3. download the OS installer and install it on top of your files